# better way to handle exception or return value

Tags: python

```
def foo(directory):
    filename = '' #dont like this
    all_files = [get from somewhere]
    try:
        if 'foo' in all_files:
            filename = 'foo'

        else:
            filename = all_files[0]
     except ValueError:
          logger.warning('Directory is empty')
     finally:
             return os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

So, here is what i have so far.. 
Is there a better way to handle this.. where we either return a value or log an error.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *easier* to beg forgiveness than to ask permission.  You can use conditional assignment for your `filename` variable, and if that's falsy, then you can emit a warning around it.

Depending on what you're really trying to accomplish, then you could use the length of `all_files` to see if the directory is truly empty.

```
def foo(directory):
    all_files = [get from somewhere] or []

    if len(all_files) == 0:
        logger.warning('Directory is empty')
        return ''
    else:
        filename = 'foo' if 'foo' in all_files else all_files[0]       
        return os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

Comment: why is `filename=""` required? ... and you speak of __eafp__ , but then use __lbyl__ ? :P (+1 all the same) ... but if all_files is `None` this will raise an exception (which may be the desired behavior)

Comment: There's probably a better way to handle that case, as well as the seemingly redundant declaration of `filename`.  When I get to a machine, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(directory):
    all_files = [get from somewhere]
    try:
        filename = 'foo' if 'foo' in all_files else all_files[0]
    except (IndexError,ValueError):
        logger.warning('Directory is empty')
    else:
        return os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

is maybe better ...

Comment: I don't see how that'd return a `ValueError`.  An `IndexError`, definitely, if the list is empty, but not a `ValueError`.

Comment: if all_files=5 maybe (or more likely None)? or some custom class ... I dunno I was going off the exception OP was catching